# Jenkins: Queue jobs if there are available Azure VM

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-virtual-machine, jenkins-groovy

**Situation:**

I have a pipeline job that executes tests in parallel. I use Azure VMs that I start/stop on each build of the job thru Powershell. Before I run the job, it checks if there are available VMs on azure (offline VMs) then use that VMs for that build. If there is no available VMs then I will fail the job. Now, one of my requirements is that instead of failing the build, I need to queue the job until one of the nodes is offline/available then use those nodes.

**Problem:**

Is there any way for me to this? Any existing plugin or a build wrapper that will allow me to queue the job based on the status of the nodes? I was forced to do this because we need to stop the Azure VM to lessen the cost usage.

As of the moment, I am still researching if this is possible or any other way for me to achieve this. I am thinking of any groovy script that will check the nodes and if there are no available, I will manually add it to the build queue until at least 1 is available. The closest plugin that I got is [Run Condition plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/run-condition/) but I think this will not work.

I am open to any approach that will help me achieve this. Thanks

Comment: May be you can try to have 2 jobs (parent and child) where parent job triggers child job as [parameterized job](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/) that too it triggers only on successful validation of node being available. See if you can use parameterized trigger plugin in such a way that it queues up a backlog but doesn't fail the job. I am not completely sure as I didn't test it out but just giving a thought that might help you!

Comment: @KrishnaG-MSFT Hi, I really appreciate your help. I thought of this one already however, the coding part of queuing it instead of failing the job is something that I need to know where to start with. I am kinda stuck and still looking for a solution as of the moment.